# How to set onclick function to dynamic textview in android?

Tags: android

I set the `onClick()` function, but when I click the text it works two times that mean I have two dynamic text view. How to resolve it?

My code:

```
TextView tView[] = new TextView [Array.length];
for(int i =1; i<Array.length; i++)
{
    tview[i] = new TextView(this);
    tview[i].setId(i);
    tview[i].setText(Array[i]);
    tview[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        Public boolean onTouch(View v ,MotionEvent event)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationcontext,"MapVal",Toast.LengthShort).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide source code of textView creation and `onClick()`

Comment: put your code of the method onclick and we will figure out the problem

Comment: [TextView tView[] = new TextView [Array.length];
for(int i =1;i<Array.lenght;i++)
{
   tview[i] = new TextView(this);
   tview[i].setId(i);
   tview[i].setText(Array[i]);
   tview[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
      Public boolean onTouch(View v ,MotionEvent event)
      {
         Toast.makerText(getApplicationcontext,"MapVal",Toast.LengthShort).show();
      }
      });
}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in using `OnTouchListener`. Event `onTouch()` is calling not one time on every tap action, but minimum two: on touch down and on touch up. Use `OnClickListener` and `setOnClickListener()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to set an onclick listener then use

urtextvw_name.setOnClicklistener()